# How to save/store the selected number of rows of my React Table into a variable? - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

This is my React Table. By default I am using 10 rows as default. I want to log (or better store into a state variable) the number of rows when we select number of rows as 5, 10 , 20 , 50 and 100 from the dropdown.

When I select 50 number of rows from the dropdown, I want to store 50 in a state variable. Similarly when I select 100 number of rows, I want to store 50 in a state variable.

This is my React Table - https://codesandbox.io/s/42nl1j300w

[image: Number of rows dropdown]

Edit 1 : I am getting this error after using the answer of @seebiscuit . This is my Code - https://codesandbox.io/s/42nl1j300w

[image: Error after change]

Edit 2 - The issue is is still there. If I give the default value of state variable pageSize as 10, when I am selecting 20, it is printing 10. After 20, if I select 50, it is giving the value as undefined.

I have found that

```
onPageSizeChange={(state) => { this.setState({ pageSize: state.pageSize }}}
```

state.pageSize is getting undefined, so that state variable pageSize is also becoming undefined.

[image: Edit 2]

Comment: Please post code, not images of code.

Comment: @jhpratt I have already posted my Sandboxed code, kindly check https://codesandbox.io/s/42nl1j300w    When I am trying to change the number of rows, I am getting undefined value in console log. First time it is giving 10, then it is always getting undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `onPageSizeChange` callback prop in `<ReactTable>` and save the `pageSize` however you want.

```
<ReactTable
  //  ... other props
  onPageSizeChange={(pageSize) => { this.setState({ pageSize }}}
/>
```

Comment: Can you kindly fork my fiddle and please show me that?

Comment: What part of the answer are you having trouble with?

Comment: I mean to say that please kindly copy your answer to my sandbox and fork it

Comment: I think you should try it and if you find you are still having trouble, I'd be happy to continue to help.

Comment: Can you check this sandbox, i used your code but still  I am getting the state undefined - https://codesandbox.io/s/42nl1j300w

Comment: I updated my answer. The parameter to `onPageSizeChange` was the current `pageSize`